# Javascript - Function to change element colour but first call never works

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function written in JS that when called, will check the current background colour of the element. If it is a certain colour then it will change to a different and if it is a another colour then it will change back to the first colour - like a toggle.

The only problem I have is that the first call of the function never work but I can't work out why. Even though I am expecting it to turn blue?

```js
function changeBgColor() {
  var x = document.getElementById(dest_1);
  var dest_bgColor = x.style.backgroundColor;

  if (dest_bgColor === "aquamarine") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "aquamarine";
  }

  return;
}
```

```css
.selectBox {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="dest_1" class="selectBox" onclick="changeBgColor()">A</a>
```

Comment: While the browser is rendering the element using the color from your style rule, this won't change the element's `style.backgroundColor`. It's a bad idea in general to rely on specific values in these properties, you should always keep/switch a separate variable, then only *set* `style.x`.

Comment: _"The [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property is used to get as well as set the **inline style** of an element. While getting, it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are **defined in the element's inline style attribute**."_

Answer (score 0):

While the browser is rendering the element using the color from your style rule, the rule won't set the element's `style.backgroundColor`. It's a bad idea in general to rely on values in these properties, you should always keep/switch a separate variable, then only *set* `style.x`.

To find out the actual value, you can use `getComputedStyle(x).backgroundColor`. In your example, this returns `rgb(127, 255, 212)` though, not `aquamarine`.

```js
var cols = ["aquamarine", "blue"];
var index = 0;

function changeBgColor() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dest_1");
  // move to next color
  index = (index + 1) % cols.length;
  x.style.backgroundColor = cols[index];
  return;
}
```

```css
.selectBox {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="dest_1" class="selectBox" onclick="changeBgColor()">A</a>
```

Comment: I'll leave this answer here for now because it shows how to use an array to switch colors.